# Using lapply() over a sequence of numbers

Tags: r

I would like to use `lapply()` in the following way:

I have a vector:

```
a<-c(1,4,6,8,9,10,11,12,14,19)
y<-1:10
lapply(a, function(x) othermatrix[othermatrix[,2,
    x] == somethingelse[y], 3, x])
```

The idea is to use the numbers specified in `a` instead of a usual sequence of consecutive numbers like `1:100`. but use a sequence of consecutive numbers as `y`

How can this be done?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you provided?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake, please see my edit. I want to use two variables in lapply one is the sequence from 'a' and another one is a sequence from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapply`:

```
a<-c(1,4,6,8,9,10,11,12,14,19)
y<-1:10

mapply(function(x,y) othermatrix[othermatrix[, 2, x] == somethingelse[y], 3, x], 
       a, y)
```

The first argument is the function. The other arguments are the objects passed to the function.